# Referencing a library project, ndk

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have an Android library project 'A'.

I have an Android project 'B' use library project 'A'.

I try to write some method from project 'A' in native c++.

I create jni folder with files:

android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := a.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and a.cpp file.

right click on project 'A' > Properties > Android Tools > Add native Support.

i add this code to 'A' project to load native class a.cpp

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("a");
}
```

after running and i get exception.

```
  01-08 21:05:58.480: E/AndroidRuntime(18945): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

It crashes when I try to load library with System.loadLibrary("a");

How to fix it?  Thx, sry for bad english.

**SOLVED**: re-build project A